# NuGet and TFS best practices

Tags: tfs, nuget

Our projects in TFS are organized like this:

```
$\DefaultCollection\ProjectName\Source  <-- source code goes here

$\DefaultCollection\ProjectName\SharedAssemblies <-- 3rd party binaries go here
```

Now that NuGet is on the scene, is there any reason to change our approach and use  NuGet's packages folder for dlls that come from NuGet-aware projects?  I'm leaning against this because

1)  it creates two places one must look for dependencies
2)  it leaves us open to one developer updating a package and breaking some dependency

That said, if anyone can report a good reason to start using NuGet in a TFS environment, I will happily present your ideas to my team as if they were my own (joke).

Comment: You don't need to store the packages from NuGet in version control, instead using `NuGet.exe` to populate a local copy from the projects' `packages.config` files: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.html

Comment: How does this work for solutions that have multiple projects?  Our main one has two web apps, two console apps, and a service.  The advantage of the dll store approach is that all of them either work or fail together.

Comment: See the link: run `nuget-exe` for each `packages.config` with the same repository folder, only missing packages will be downloaded (this could also be a per-project pre-build step).

Comment: There is an open issue on codeplex for this and there is lots of discussion there. http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/215

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Nuget 1.6 now allows for packages not present to be downloaded dynamically upon build.  So you can now check in to source control without the .dlls, but the build itself will pull the correct package.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: How do you tell [nuget package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1) to point to a folder in TFS not a physical path??? Everyone's workspace may be different so this MIGHT not be accurate for every one:  `<add key=" repositoryPath" value=" C:\myteam\teampackages" />`

Comment: I know this is old, but just in case anyone else is wondering: Simply don't put a file path. Put a relative path. e.g. <add key="repositoryPath" value="SharedAssemblies"